# Instruction addresses through Instruction Set Encoding

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

I am trying to solve a question related to instruction encoding.I have a processor with an instruction length of 18-bits and I need to check the possibility of whether the following instruction encodings are possible.
a) 5 three address instructions
b) 95 two address instructions
c) 31 one address instructions
d) 70 zero address instructions

For now I am able to do the (a) part as follows

xxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx

000 xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx

001 xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx

010 xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx

011 xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx

100 xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx

I can get my five 3 address instructions from the above encodings but now i 
need 95 two address instructions and further ones but I can't seem to solve the (b) part as the three instructions are left and i don't know how to do the remaining.

101 xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
110 xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
111 xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx

These are the remaining three instructions and from them i also need to encode for (c) and (d) part.So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm - I can do a) through c) but I'm finding trouble fitting in the 70 zero-address instructions - I can only fit in 32.

Comment: Yeah I'm also facing the same thing right now ... I guess d) option is not possible.Can you share your method of solving the first three, that would be of help.

Comment: Sure - see below.

Answer (score 0):

You're not spelling it out in the question, but I get the impression that those `xxxxx` fields are 5-bit address fields in the 3-address instructions. If that's the case then, as you show, what you have left after step `a)` are the three prefixes 101, 110, and 111.

For encoding the 2-address instructions, then, you have the 3rd address field at your disposal in addition to the three 'free' prefixes. Since an address field is 5 bits, it can encode 32 different values. Three times 32 is 96, which is good, because you 'only' need 95 for the two-address instructions, so those could be encoded as follows:

```
101 00000 xxxxx xxxxx ... 101 11111 xxxxx xxxxx 
110 00000 xxxxx xxxxx ... 110 11111 xxxxx xxxxx 
111 00000 xxxxx xxxxx ... 111 11110 xxxxx xxxxx
```

The final unused 8-bit prefix, `111 11111`, can then be used to encode the 1-address instructions along with the next - now available - address slot:

```
111 11111 00000 xxxxx ... 111 11111 11110 xxxxx
```

Which leaves the 13-bit prefix `111 11111 11111` for encoding the zero-address instructions:

```
111 11111 11111 00000 ... 111 11111 11111 11111
```

Unfortunately, since there's only the one 5-bit address field available for encoding the remaining zero-address instructions, I can only fit in 32 of those, not the 70 that are called for.

Comment: Hmm I didn't spell correctly about address fields but I got it now the d) option is not possible.Really appreciate your help!